# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter's symbol "F"

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

In `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```java
/** Map of letters to fields. */
private static final Map<Character, TemporalField> FIELD_MAP = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // SDF = SimpleDateFormat
    // ...
    FIELD_MAP.put('F', ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);  // SDF, LDML
    // ...
}
```

It shows that the symbol "F" may have the same meaning in SimpleDateFormatter(SDF).

In SDF, the symbol "F" means the ordinal of designated day of week, such as "the second Sunday in May" , Mother's Day (US).
With SDF, I can define Mother's Day (US) in 2021 by "2021-05-2-Sun" with pattern "yyyy-MM-F-EEE".
But any pattern with the symbol "F" with DateTimeFormatter may cause a DateTimeParseException.
I found an issue that is already "fixed":
[[JDK-8169482]java.time.DateTimeFormatter javadoc: F is not week-of-month](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169482)
But it only "fixed" the javadoc! Σ(っ °Д °;)っ
The symbol "F" is still with an undefined behavior.

The confusing description in SDF "F: Day of week in month" may be the reason.

Comment: The only thing wrong here is the comment, which should have said `(different in SDF)`. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: The behaviour of `F` is totally defined, by the way, see what [`ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) actually means.

Comment: If F means the ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, how to use it in formatter's pattern? There's no way to define a date with ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, without ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the resolution of the bug was to fix the documentation, rather than to fix the `DateTimeFormatter`'s implementation, it seems like `F` meaning `ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` is actually intended, and it's only that the `// SDF` comment hasn't been corrected.

And because it means [`ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH), a date such as "2021-05-2-Sun" doesn't make much sense. You've only given a month and a year, and the day of the week. That's not enough information to figure out which day of month it is. It doesn't happen with "2021-05-2-Sun", but in cases like "2021-05-2-Mon", the day of week (Mon), and the aligned day of week (2) can even say different things about which day of week it should be. :)

To parse an "nth day-of-week", you need `ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH`, which [`DateFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) doesn't have a symbol for. (Note that `W` is the *non-aligned* week of month.) But don't worry, you can append any `TemporalField` into the pattern with [`appendValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValue(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)
        .appendPattern("-EEE").toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2021-05-2-Sun", formatter));
// 2021-05-09
```